use that an argument has a certain pattern when proving an identity
From the PLFA I'm trying to prove All-++-≃, that is, that
All-++-≃  : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (xs ys : List A) → All P (xs ++ ys) ≃ (All P xs × All P ys)

My problem is with
  FromTo : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (xs ys : List A) → (u : All P (xs ++ ys)) → from xs ys (to xs ys u) ≡ u

I proved the simple base cases, but I'm having problems with this pattern:
  FromTo (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´) = ?

The basic problem is that I need to assume that to xs ys u´ has a certain shape
to xs ys u´ = ⟨ Pxs , Pys ⟩

because that allows me to use the definition of
to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´)

and I can go from there. The problem is that I don't know how to write that. Is a syntactical problem if you wish. I tried using a helper function:
  helper : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (x : A) → (xs ys : List A) → (u : P x) → (u´ : All P (xs ++ ys)) → (All P xs × All P ys) → from (x :: xs) ys (to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´)) ≡ (u ∷ u´)

and then
  FromTo (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´) = helper x xs ys u u´ (to xs ys u´)

but also I couldn't write the definition of the helper function. So my problem is basically how to write in agda the proof that in paper looks so simple. I just need to write that I assume that to xs ys u´ has some pattern ⟨ Pxs , Pys ⟩ and use that.

I can't really tell what you're asking and I suspect you've identified the wrong problem, but that case is solved by a recursive call:
  FromTo (x ∷ xs) ys (u ∷ u′) = cong (u ∷_) (FromTo xs ys u′)

Agda already knows that to (x ∷ xs) ys (u ∷ u′) is of the form ⟨ Pxs , Pys ⟩ in that branch, so the first "layer" computes away and you just need to use the induction hypothesis.

Honestly that answer is too abstract for me. I need to see the calculation. To me it looks like magic and I only understand it after doing the calculation.

See my other response https://stackoverflow.com/a/79034648/8250385, because at first I couldnt understand why that answer worked.

"Why it works" was your half of the job. Glad you figured it out!

What I could figure out is this.
A first try would be something like this. Assuming that "to xs ys u´ = ⟨ Pxs , Pys ⟩"
  helper : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (x : A) → (xs ys : List A) → (u : P x) → (u´ : All P (xs ++ ys)) → (from xs ys (to xs ys u´) ≡ u´) → from (x :: xs) ys (to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´)) ≡ (u ∷ u´)
  helper x xs ys u u´ q =
    begin
          from (x :: xs) ys (to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´))
        ≡⟨⟩
          from (x :: xs) ys (⟨ u ∷ Pxs , Pys ⟩)
        ≡⟨⟩
          u ∷ from xs ys (⟨ Pxs , Pys ⟩)
        ≡⟨⟩
          u ∷ from xs ys (to xs ys u´)
        ≡⟨ cong (u ∷_) q ⟩
          u ∷ u´
    ∎

  FromTo (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´) = helper x xs ys u u´ (FromTo xs ys u´)

The problem of course is that the variables Pxs and Pys don't exist. But since we are  not using any hypothesis in the intermediate "≡⟨⟩" steps (only definitions), we can delete those steps:
  helper : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (x : A) → (xs ys : List A) → (u : P x) → (u´ : All P (xs ++ ys)) → (from xs ys (to xs ys u´) ≡ u´) → from (x :: xs) ys (to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´)) ≡ (u ∷ u´)
  helper x xs ys u u´ q =
    begin
          from (x :: xs) ys (to (x :: xs) ys (u ∷ u´))
        ≡⟨ cong (u ∷_) q ⟩
          u ∷ u´
    ∎

and this works. And that proof is simply cong (u ∷_) (FromTo xs ys u´). @Naïm Favier this is how I would have reached that conclusion, simply writing "cong (u ∷_) (FromTo xs ys u′)" is a little too indirect for me :).

Maybe this is what you're missing: (dependent) pair types have η-equality, which means that every pair x is definitionally equal to ⟨ x .proj₁ , x .proj₂ ⟩. So instead of Pxs you could write to xs ys u′ .proj₁ and so on.
